# Empty array after adding elements using Titanium Appcelerator mobile 1.7.2

Tags: javascript, arrays, titanium, appcelerator

I'm using Titanium Appcelerator mobile API 1.7.2.

When creating an array, I'm getting some odd results. Is it my syntax?

```
container.textBoxArray = new Array();
container.textBoxArray[0] = createPasswordTextField(options, '0%');
container.textBoxArray[1] = createPasswordTextField(options, '25%');
Ti.API.log(container.textBoxArray == null);
Ti.API.log('len: ' + container.textBoxArray.length);
```

The results of the output are 0 (for false) and 'len: 0' respectively. Anyone know why?

Adam

Edit:
createPasswordTextField is essentially

```
function createPasswordTextField(options, left){
    return Ti.UI.createTextField( options... )
}
```

Comment: As it turns out:
`container.textBoxArray = [createPasswordTextField(options, '0%'), createPasswordTextField(options, '25%'), createPasswordTextField(options, '50%'), createPasswordTextField(options, '75%')];`

successfully creates the array.

It was the Ti.API.log() that was crashing, so I commented them and ... it works? I don't understand this platform.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having problems with Titanium and Arrays too. What you could do, is try this:

```
container.textBoxArray = [];
container.textBoxArray.push(createPasswordTextField(options, '0%'));
container.textBoxArray.push(createPasswordTextField(options, '25%'));
Ti.API.log(container.textBoxArray == null);
Ti.API.log('len: ' + container.textBoxArray.length);
```

Comment: That is the syntax I had before and it works. However when I try to access the array at a later time the contents are gone. I thought maybe it was a memory lifetime issue so I was experimenting with different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

the log statement should look like this to view arrays contents

```
Ti.API.log(JSON.stringify(container.textBoxArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this as well. When adding an array to a TiProxy object (View, Window, button etc.) it doesn't work as expected.  You need to manipulate the array 'off' the proxy, then re-set it.  I don't know if this is a bug or just a limitation of properties on TiProxy objects.  Here is an example that behaves the same on iOS under Titanium Mobile SDK 1.7.5:

```
var proxy = Ti.UI.createView();  //this can be any TiProxy object

proxy.someArray = [];
proxy.someArray.push( '1' );
proxy.someArray.push( '2' );
Ti.API.info("Array modified directly on TiProxy object" );
Ti.API.info(proxy.someArray );

var myArray = [];
myArray.push( '1' );
myArray.push( '2' );
proxy.someArray = myArray;
Ti.API.info("Array modified outside TiProxy object" );
Ti.API.info( proxy.someArray );

proxy.someArray.push( '3' );
Ti.API.info("This will be unchanged" );
Ti.API.info(proxy.someArray );

var changeArray = proxy.someArray;
changeArray.push('3');
proxy.someArray = changeArray;
Ti.API.info("This is how you must do it." );
Ti.API.info(proxy.someArray );
```

returns:

```
[INFO] Array modified directly on TiProxy object
[INFO] []
[INFO] Array modified outside TiProxy object
[INFO] [ 1,  2 ]
[INFO] This will be unchanged
[INFO] [ 1,  2 ]
[INFO] This is how you must do it.
[INFO] [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Finding out the behavour on Android is a lot harder bacause `Ti.API.info(proxy.someArray );` just returns an object reference.