# Unable to update values in arrays

Tags: javascript, for-loop, titanium-mobile

I am using Titanium Appcelerator.

I have an array of buttons that I've created for a game. There is one array of buttons per player. 
I also have an array of player objects, and each one has a "score" property.

When a player presses one of the buttons, which all have an assigned value, the player to whom this button belongs is to have his score updated.

Here is how I am creating a set of buttons for each player:

```
for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
    playerButtons[i] = Titanium.UI.createButton({
        myPlayer: thePlayer,
        index: i,
        value: 50,
        touchEnabled: true,
    });
}
```

I am setting a property of "myPlayer" to the player that the button belongs to. This is so that I can associate it to the player when pressing it, and so that I know which score to update. This for loop is in a function that gets called when the game begins, and is passed the "thePlayer" variable which holds the player object to which it belongs to. However, there seems to be a disconnect here. Example: If player 1's score is, let's say, 0, and a button is pressed that's worth 50, I do either of these things, which have no effect on the object property for the player's score:

("this" is the button pressed)

```
var totalScore = 50;
this.myPlayer.score = totalScore;
player[1].score = totalScore;
Ti.API.debug(player[1].score) //this prints out 0, not 50
```

No idea why I can't change a player's score. I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays assigned to TiProxy objects don't behave as expected. See my answer here: [Empty array after adding elements using Titanium Appcelerator mobile 1.7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795052/empty-array-after-adding-elements-using-titanium-appcelerator-mobile-1-7-2/8196970#8196970)

Comment: Hi Jeff, do they automatically get assigned to TiProxy objects? If not I'm not doing so.

Comment: They shouldn't get assigned automatically. Perhaps the problem is setting a property on an array element?